# python itertools.combinations deleted

Tags: python, variables, combinations, python-itertools

I've noticed that the itertools.combinations object in Python can seemingly delete itself:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = itertools.combinations( 'ABCD', 2 )
>>> print list( x )
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
>>> print list( x )
[]
```

Why has the object x changed here? I haven't assigned x to be anything.

Comment: It's a generator. Generator are consumed when read. Convert it to a list if you want to use it multiple times.

Comment: The values of the iterator aren't stored, to save memory. It can also speed up things when it concerns a long loop, since you don't first have to calculate the values, and then step through them separately; an iterator calculates its values on the go (compare range versus xrange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` (along with many of the other `itertools` methods) return a generator expression. Generators can only be read exactly 1 time.

You can read more about generators [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Comment: Is there any reason for this, or is it just an arbitrary rule?

Comment: @bill: there are ever so many more sources that can produce information just the once. Network sockets, for example. And it is more efficient if you don't hold on to intermediary results in memory. So this is *by design*.

Comment: For efficiency. That is the primary purpose of generators.

Comment: They can also go on forever ...  and with something like combinations it can be very easy to make one where the list would consume entire memory of the machine

Answer (score 4):

You are creating an *generator*. If you want to use the values later on save them to a list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = itertools.combinations( 'ABCD', 2 )
>>> list_of_x = list( x )
>>> print(list_of_x)
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
 >>> print(list_of_x)
[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Iterator` works just once.
You can't use `iterator` object again.

Iterator works as `generators` including `next()` function and raise `Stop Iteration` error,
 you can read about it [here](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html)